# Macros Disabled Suddenly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bit of an odd one that I'm hoping someone else has experienced and knows how to fix!

I created a macro enabled workbook that's been used as a template/saved as to create one for each user in our team (about 50). All of the workbooks are saved in the same location/folder as .xlsm files and have been working for about 6mths now.

Now one of them seems to have disabled the macros suddenly and won't allow them to be re-enabled!

The workbook that has "broken" shows the "*Macros have been disabled.*" security warning message/banner with the "Enable Content" button when opening, but pressing the "Enable Content" button doesn't do anything.

Notably, when I open one of the other workbooks, the security warning message reads "*Some active content has been disabled. Click for more details.*" and once enabled they work as expected.

All of the macro code is still visible in my broken book and can be manually run from the VBE.

I've checked the trust centre settings for macros (which is set to disable with notification & the "trust VBA" box is ticked) and for ActiveX (which is set to prompt before enabling & Safe mode is ticked) and I've checked the add-in settings (nothing ticked in trust centre).

I've had this happen once before (perhaps coincidently with a sheet that was being edited by the user whose book is now broken) and couldn't figure it out so ended up just creating a new book for them.

Does anyone have some suggestions on what causes this to happen and how to fix it without having to create a new workbook?

Comment: First this looks more like beeing an issue with the Excel settings than an issue with the file. Make sure the path you have these files is trusted in the *Trust Center* of each Excel using them, so macros in those path are trusted and get enabled! • If you really suspect that the files get broken (which can happen quite easily with the `xslm`/`xlsx` format as I figured out) then try saving those files in the binary `xlsb` format (this can contain macros too) the binary files are much more stable agains corruption and even smaller in size.

Comment: If you can run them from the VBE then macros are not disabled in that file. What should they be doing that they aren't?

Comment: If the code runs from a button press is the button still connected to the correct code?  Never under estimate a users ability to right click a button, select "Assign Macro", panic and delete the entry....

Comment: The code is still assigned to the buttons. It appears that it's more an issue with the ActiveX content. I've got a worksheet_selectionChange code that makes a command button visible in the selected cell. When hovering where the button should appear I can see the 4 way arrows and can select the shape (as if in design mode) but it's not a functional button! None of the other buttons on in this book can be used either/all appear as if in design mode.